# explain these select statements!

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I can not get the difference betwwn these statements? would you please help me,I have read some sample of select statements but I did not get these ones.

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A = (SELECT NULL);
SELECT 'C' FROM T WHERE A = ANY (SELECT NULL);    
SELECT 'D' FROM T WHERE A = A;
```

I use MySQL

EDITED: also it has a conditional part that : SET ANSI_NULLS is OFF

Answer (score 3):

**ANSI_NULL ON**

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A = (SELECT NULL);
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A = NULL;
```

Which always returns an empty set because anything compared to NULL returns NULL, not TRUE. You might try this:

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A IS NULL;
```

The second query is basically the same and will return an empty set:

```
SELECT 'C' FROM T WHERE A = ANY (SELECT NULL);
```

If A has a value, the following will return all rows:

```
SELECT 'D' FROM T WHERE A = A;
```

Except, if A IS NULL, it will return an empty set.

**ANSI_NULL OFF**

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A = (SELECT NULL);
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT 'B' FROM T WHERE A = NULL;
```

Which returns all rows where A IS NULL.

The second query is basically the same and will return rows where A IS NULL:

```
SELECT 'C' FROM T WHERE A = ANY (SELECT NULL);
```

The following will always return all rows, regardless if A IS NULL:

```
SELECT 'D' FROM T WHERE A = A;
```

Comment: exceuse me I have asked a question before like
SELECT 'A' FROM T WHERE A = NULL; 
 and the others told me that it will return some rows which contains A character!!!

Comment: @user329820 the above post is correct. To compare with NULL, you must use IS. Try it out yourself!

Comment: Also, I think most people answering that other question mentioned that you must change `=` to `IS`.

Comment: also I found this site ,please see it ,thanks http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188048.aspx

Comment: if the column A was set with null value then the result of first statement in the above will be false?(ANSI-NULLS is OFF)